# VLC in Mac does not show video window

Tags: vlc

I have just installed VLC for Mac, after I added a video file to my play list all I can see is this window + the audio played.

Please let me know how can I show the video playback?

[image]

Comment: how did you get that video? from youtube download? it shows it as QuickTime file?

Comment: Yes, YouTube download. It is a mp4 file.

Comment: I know this is trivial, but make sure to Enable Video in VLC preferences.

Answer (score 1):

That's the playlist window.

On **Mac OS X**:

Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to switch modes, or click on `Window` > `Playlist`.

On **Windows**:

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to switch modes, or click on `View` > `Playlist`.

Comment: From View menu I don't see the Playlist.

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another thing to check: I found that when I doubt-clicked a video to play it, VLC opened, which I could tell from the dock, but I didn't see a window with the video playing in it. I finally figured out that VLC was opening the video window in a new "Space", so after it started I would have to slide over to the next Space. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced something similar with VLC. Typically, I play vids in full screen on my second display connected to my MacBook. When I am not connected to the external display and I play a vid, VLC seems to want to still play in this dual display mode. So it's like it's playing on a ghost second display.

If this is your situation, the easiest solution is to **simply press 'Escape'.** That pulls the vid out of full screen mode (on the ghost second monitor) and displays it in windowed mode.

From there you should be good.

(P.S. *I just wrote this same thing in another similar VLC post today... Must be something in the air.*)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the preferences and select "Show video within main window"